# Scale button font to fit both width and height of button in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button on a form with AutoSize set to false which looks like this:

[image: Button]

I want it so that whenever the button's text is changed, the font scales up or down so that it perfectly fits the width and height of the button.

I've looked online and found methods using the `TextRenderer.MeasureString` function, or brute-forcing it with a while loop, however the ones I found only accounted for the width of the control and not the height, meaning it can end up looking like this:

[image]

Here is the example I tried:

```
private void ScaleFont(Control c)
{
      SizeF extent = TextRenderer.MeasureText(c.Text, c.Font);

      float hRatio = c.Height / extent.Height;
      float wRatio = c.Width / extent.Width;
      float ratio = (hRatio < wRatio) ? hRatio : wRatio;

       float newSize = c.Font.Size * ratio;

       c.Font = new Font(c.Font.FontFamily, newSize, c.Font.Style);
}
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is an image showing what I want to achieve:

[image]

As you can see, the text is spread out into multiple lines and it perfectly fits the control.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you're actually looking for? What you have and what you don't want is clear, what you want to achieve, not exactly.

Comment: @Jimi I've edited the post to make it a bit more clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: I doubt if there is a way to compute this beforehand - you don't know when/where the text will wrap for different sizes. I think you would need to run a loop.